# How do I automatically implement comparison for structs with floats in Rust?

Tags: comparison, rust

I'm trying to automatically "derive" comparison functionality for a simple struct like this:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Vec3 {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}
```

However, Rust 1.15.1 complains:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f64: std::cmp::Eq` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     x: f64,
  |     ^^^^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Eq` is not implemented for `f64`
  |
  = note: required by `std::cmp::AssertParamIsEq`
```

What exactly am I supposed to do to allow the derivation of a default implementation here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Rust intentionally does not implement `Eq` for float types.  This [reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2h86qk/dealing_with_floats_and_lack_of_eq/) may shed some more light on why, but the tl;dr is that floating point numbers aren't totally orderable so bizarre edge cases are unavoidable.

However, if you want to add comparison to your struct, you can derive `PartialOrd` instead.  This will give you implementations of the comparative and equality operators:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
struct Vec3 {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}

fn main() {
    let a = Vec3 { x: 1.0, y: 1.1, z: 1.0 };
    let b = Vec3 { x: 2.0, y: 2.0, z: 2.0 };

    println!("{}", a < b); //true
    println!("{}", a <= b); //true
    println!("{}", a == b); //false
}
```

The difference between `Eq` and `PartialEq` (and hence between `Ord` and `PartialOrd`) is that `Eq` requires that the `==` operator form an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), whereas `PartialOrd` only requires that `==` and `!=` are inverses.  So just as with floats themselves, you should keep that in mind when doing comparisons on instances of your struct.