# Implement trait for base type (float)

Tags: rust, numbers, polymorphism, traits, parametric-polymorphism

I want to work with rings, so I have a trait `RingOps` and I want `float` to be a part of it. I think `float` implements each supertype so deriving would be great, but if not, how to do this?

```
trait RingOps: Add<Output=Self> + Mul<Output=Self> + Eq + Debug
    where Self: std::marker::Sized {}
  
impl RingOps for float {}
```

Here's the error

```
    error[E0412]: cannot find type `float` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:18
  |
8 | impl RingOps for float {}
  |                  ^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0277]: the trait bound `{float}: RingOps` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:44:32
   |
13 |     Input(&'a str, T),
   |     ----------------- required by `Circuit::Input`
...
44 |         Box::new(Circuit::Input("a", 2.0)),
   |                                      ^^^ the trait `RingOps` is not implemented for `{float}`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `float` type in Rust, you have to implement this for `f32` and `f64` respectively. An example:

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;

trait Trait: Display {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("i am {}", self);
    }
}

impl Trait for f32 {}
impl Trait for f64 {}

fn main() {
    1.5_f32.print(); // prints "i am 1.5"
    1.5_f64.print(); // prints "i am 1.5"
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e21049c2319d4911a4fa4cbc768beb6)

Comment: Cool! This got me further than I thought, does `f32` not implement `std::cmp::Eq` though?

Comment: Ah nvm found it, it's a design decision https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958178/how-do-i-automatically-implement-comparison-for-structs-with-floats-in-rust

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a [crate](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/1.0.2/ordered_float/) which provides useful `Eq`, `Ord`, and `Hash` instances for (a newtype wrapper of) floats. These implementations are not IEEE-compliant (as IEEE fails all of those traits' requirements), but they are super handy and, IMO, more intuitive than the IEEE definitions.